# android upload image in certain directory via php

Tags: php, android, database

I am trying to upload photos into certain directory in my database from my android apps. I'm quite new in php so I make this php code:

```
$photoName = $_POST['photoName'];
$photo = base64_decode($_POST['photo']);
if (!file_exists('photos')) {
    mkdir('photos', 0777, true);
}
$fp = fopen($photoName, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $photo);
if(fclose($fp)){
    $response["message"] = "Photo uploaded!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}else{
    $response["message"] = "Fail to upload!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I have successfully create the directory ("photos/") and upload the image into the root folder. The question is, when i upload the image, i want it to be placed in the directory. Can someone tell me how i should modify my code?

Comment: this stands at being incorrect `$_POST['photo']` since your input would be a file. So, missing code (html form) makes your question next to impossible to answer. Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I think he is using `base64_encode` string from android.

Comment: @SubinThomas the link I left them should in its own right help them how to move the file to a preferred folder.

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the file inside directory, you need to open file inside that directory.

So instead of

```
$fp = fopen($photoName, 'w');  //create file in root directory
```

Use

```
$fp = fopen('./photos/'.$photoName, 'w');   //create file in photos directory
```

Comment: thank you for your help :) sorry my reputation haven't allowed me to upvote yet XD